# Saving frostbite tomato plants

Tags: tomatoes, frost

Late frost covered but not s they can be saved [image]

Comment: Your photo is so blurry, it’s impossible to see how severely they are damaged or what may be a solution. Please [edit] your post and give us a non-blurry photo, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime it is faster to start again. Especially tomatoes because they grow so fast when it gets warm. When I was first growing vegetables ; I started them under lights. I put tomatoes out early, covered them on cold nights, put clear plastic over them on cool cloudy days. Kept them growing. About the first of June , the 2 acre farm across the road buried wilted , small, bare root tomato plants. In a few weeks his plants were bigger than mine. My garden started getting shade about 5 PM. The farm was full sun.

Comment: I once did an experiment with tomatoes and early planting, using plastic cylinders made up of tubes you fill with water as protection from cold (WoWs). I started all tomatoes on the same day and grew them under lights inside. I planted the first tomato in a WoW on 4/15 (Last frost date was around 5/15 in those days), Planted the next on 4/30 in a WoW, the next on 5/1 in a WoW and the last after 5/15 as normal. The last plant was pretty etiolated. First plant to bear fruit was the last planted. Last to bear was the first planted. Plant new and keep warm, then put out.when first leaves are out.